# clear label of a form from the button of another form in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

First, I apologize for my english, I'm still learning
I have a project in visual basic .net
It has two forms. One is the main and the other are called "details". "Details" must appears when click a label on the main form. When I close "details" form, I need to clear or reset (___.text = "") all the labels inside it. I tryed programming a close button or even in the FormClosing Event but it doesn't work. 
The main form has a "New" button that cleans every label and textbox inside it. So I tryed to clear the labels of "Details" form from this button (Form2.Label1.Text = ""). But it doesn't work.
If I click "New" and then I click "Details" to open Details form, the labels had the old values. I need it clean.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the code of what you tried?

Comment: Please read this *carefully*: [Ask].  Then fix your question.

Comment: Also, regardless of your language, I'm sure your native language makes use of paragraphs and proper punctuation. It would make your questions easier to decipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display your "Details" Form with `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, then call the PerformClick() method of your "New" Button:

```
' ... from within the "Main" Form ...
Dim details As New frmDetails
details.ShowDialog() ' <-- code STOPS here until "details" is dismissed
btnNew.PerformClick() ' now click the "New" button
```